# Windows application: align ListView items in a group to center of line

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a windows application in C# and I want to rank people based of their score, into 3 levels; the one with highest score at first level, next 3 highest at second level, and others at third level.

I've implemented this, as shown in picture, using ListView with 3 groups successfully; my question is: can I align items in each group to center? Items are aligned to left

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No this is not really possible without `owner-drawing` the `ListView`.

The reason is the the `ShowGroups` property.

If it were false you could  calculate the `Position` for each `ListViewItem`..

Here is how to modify the position of a `ListViewItem`:

```
ListViewItem lvi = listView1.Items[3];
lvi.Position = new Point(lvi.Position.X + 50, lvi.Position.Y);
lvi.Text = "X testing X";
```

But this will not have an effect if the `ListView` has `ShowGroups = true` unfortunately. Nor is calculating the offset a simple task; after all it would differ depending on the number of `Items` **both** in a group and in the row.

So you would have to ownerdraw the `ListView`, which will work but will have the same problems when determining the exact positions.

And centering two items would make the whole layout look jagged and ugly, imo.

Maybe the simplest solution is a workaround: Simply add a dummy item where needed. Its image would be transparent or its `ImageIndex = -1;` and its text empty or blank. You would insert it into every group with an odd numer of items which is not divisible by the maximum of items in a row. In your case 3. Or perhaps it is enough to check if the group contains only one item..

Here is an example:

```
void InsertBlankItem(ListView lv, ListViewGroup lvg)
{
    ListViewItem lvOld = g.Items[0];
    lvg.Items.Remove(lvOld);
    ListViewItem lviBlank = new ListViewItem() { Text = " ", ImageIndex = -1 };
    lviBlank.Group = lvg;
    listView1.Items.Add(lviBlank);
    lvg.Items.Insert(1, lvOld);
}
```

This adds a blank item and moves the first item to the end..:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewGroup g in listView1.Groups)
    {
        if (g.Items.Count == 1) InsertBlankItem(listView1, g); 

    }
}
```

Of course now you have a clickable dummy item in your `ListView`..

If you want to re-order more `Items` within a group you need to remove them all into a List and re-add them in the new order.

[image][image]